# z-index issue internet explorer compatibility mode and 7

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a menu User control on in my web application which on hover drops its menu list below. the problem I am facing is, in IE 7 or IE 10 compatibility mode, the image on my page is visible above the menu drop down inspite of setting the z-index property of menu drop down high.

Please provide me a relevant solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parent element that contains the menu list that has the `position: relative` set on it needs to have a z-index higher than that of the body. `z-index` also works on a top down basis in that elements that are declared after the menu have a higher `z-index` than the elements before them.

tl;dr..

Set the menu to have a higher element than the content

(example with inline styles)

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="nav" style="position:relative; z-index: 2">
        <ul>
           <li>
               Blah
               <ul class="drop-menu">
                   <li>drop item</li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content" style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hi, this solved my issue, but I have a jquery UI slider on my page whose position relative is set, I cannot move the css of it in any ways. Due to this the above solution cannot be applied for the same.